# Python Telegram bot as a package

Tags: python, heroku, bots, python-telegram-bot

I am new to python and telegram bots. I was wondering for larger scalable bots, how can we use them as a package? I don't know how to approach this issue. I am aware of creating python packages(`setup.py` and whatnot) but not sure how to utilize that in a bot. So instead of having a `bot.py` and putting all code in it, how would I use a packaged app to do this? 
Also if you could tell me how I could run this package in something like heroku I would be happy.
I use the [python-telegram-bot wrapper](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not absolutely sure I'm on point here, but what I did when creating my simple bot was I actually **did** have a bot.py file, among other helper files and configurations, all inside a single GitHub repository.
 
Then when I wanted to run it I just cloned my repo to the server (runs on an AWS EC2) and started bot.py.
 
The bot was listening for chats/commands/what not and this was about it.
 
So my advice is pretty straight forward - clone it from your own repository.
You can check out my example [here](https://github.com/evyatarmeged/telegram-bot).

Comment: Actually, I was asking about running the bot using classes and packaging. that repo helped me. Thanks!